# "Attempt to create two animations for cell" Crash on ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

Here is my first post on stackoverflow. Any of your help will be greatly appreciated!

I am totally new to ios development. As a practice, I am trying to develop a simple app that keeps track of diffrent items in my lab. Each item has a to-one relationship to its location and each location has a to-many relationship to different items.

I have a `UITableViewController(LocationListTableViewController)` that uses `NSFectchedResultController` as its data source for the tableview. The tableview controller is also conformed to `NSFetchedResultController` Delegate to keep all the `NSManagedObject` updated.

Once a location on the `LocationListTableViewController` is tapped, a `DetailedTableViewController` will be pushed and shows the items at that location. This `DetailedTableViewController` has an `NSUndoManager` instance variable to support canceling of changes. I use a `NSMutableArray` as the data source of the `DetailedTableViewController`:

```
NSSet *items = self.location.items;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *array = [[items allObjects]sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
// itemList is the data source for the table view
self.itemList = [array mutableCopy];
```

When the "Edit" button is tapped, Users can delete items and those item's location is set to nil.  The deleted Items are transferred to a "changedItem" NSMutableArray so that the change can be canceled:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (!changedItems)
       changedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Set the company attribute of selected company to nil
    Item *editingItem = [itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    editingItem.company = nil;

    // Add to changedItem array to support canceling
    [changedItems addObject:editingItem];
    // Remove from the data source array
    [itemList removeObject:editingItem];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

I put a Cancel button as the left bar button item, and when it's tapped:

```
 [undoManager endUndoGrouping];
 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.location.managedObjectContext;
 [moc rollback];

 // Add item from changedItem array back to itemList array (data source array)
 if ([changedItems count] > 0) {
      [itemList addObjectsFromArray:changedItems];
      [itemList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
  }
```

Here comes the problem. When I delete more than one item and try to cancel these change, the app does not crash but I get the error message:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableViewSupport.m:599

Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo (null)
```

When only deleting one item, the app seems fine.

This is very anoying. Is there anybody could help me with this?

Many thanks!

Comment: sean, as you are deleting rows are you also updating the datasource properly(fetchResultsController)?

Comment: don't mess with the tableView if the NSFetchedResultsController messes with it too. I.E. remove the line `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`. And the rest of the code looks remove-worthy too. Your manual undo tracking makes little sense. And neither does it make sense to offer a delete interface and then instead of deleting the object you just set it's relationship to nil. I would suggest to make it work without undo and then add the undo code later.

Comment: Thanks so much for your inputs! The data source of the DetailedTableViewController is a mutable array(fetchedResultController is the data source for the ListTableViewController). If deleting [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade], the row cannot be deleted at all. @Ravin, the itemList is the data source for the detailedviewcontroller and I removed item from it. How can I update the fetchedResultController in the ListTableViewController to delete the deleted items? I really thank you experienced developers for this!

Comment: As for setting the relationship to nil, I think when removing an item from a location, what's happened most likely is that the item is no longer at the specified location, instead of the lab doesn't possess the item anymore. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The cell probably doesn't exist - try NSLogging its value or making sure it's created properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just have a try:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```